# BufferedReader skip lines assets file java android

Tags: java, android, file, inputstream, bufferedreader

I'm trying to read a .txt-file that's located in my assets folder in an Android project. Search the file, read the file with the InputStreamer and the BufferedReader works just fine, but the problem is: it doesn't read ALL the lines. So when I want to add a line to an ArrayList for further use, not all the lines are present in this list. This is my code:

```
InputStream inputStream;
BufferedReader br;
try {
    inputStream = getResources().getAssets().open("KeyMapping.txt");
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    final ArrayList<String> viewList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = null;

    //Add every line (except the first) to an arrayList
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && (line = br.readLine()) != "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,char") {
        viewList.add(line);
    }

    br.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The format of my .txt-file is like this:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8/char
1,,,,1,,,/a
2,,,,1,,,/b
3,,,,1,,,/c
,1,,,1,,,/d
,2,,,1,,,/e
,3,,,1,,,/f
,,1,,1,,,/g
,,2,,1,,,/h
,,3,,1,,,/i
,,,,1,,,1/j
,,,,1,,,2/k
,,,,1,,,3/l
1,,,,2,,,/m
2,,,,2,,,/n
3,,,,2,,,/o
,1,,,2,,,/p
,2,,,2,,,/q
,3,,,2,,,/r
,,1,,2,,,/s
,,2,,2,,,/t
,,3,,2,,,/u
,,,,2,,,1/v
,,,,2,,,2/w
,,,,2,,,3/x
...
```

Only a few of these lines will be added to the ArrayList, does anyone know why?

Comment: You're calling `readLine()` twice in each loop iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && (line = br.readLine()) != "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,char")
```

This line reads 2 lines from the stream, and processes the 2nd line always.

Also, you cannot compare strings with `!=` operator. Use `String.equals()` method.

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
 if(line.equals("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,char"))
   continue;
 //add if it's not that string
 viewList.add(line);
}
```